Comparison if GSEA in a single plot for 3 different cell types
I have 3 cell types in seurat object and I want to compare GSEA for all the 3 cell types and plot it together in a single plot. How to do it any suggestion, which plot is suitable? The target gene set contains 300 genes.
I am expecting an answer as to which plot will be better. Or is there any better way to check which cell type has most activity of that target gene set I am using?
